# Why does an insert() break wrapAsync'd child_process.spawn() handlers in a Meteor method?

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

I'm trying to use `child_process.spawn()` in a Meteor method. I want to capture the PID, stdout, stderr, and exit code from an external process, and store all that in the database.

Everything worked until I added that first `insert()` call. With that `insert()`, only one 'dummy' document is inserted into the database. I get no error messages in the server console. If I comment out that first `insert()`, the other `insert()` calls succeed.

```
// server/app.js
var spawn = Npm.require('child_process').spawn;

Meteor.methods({
  start: function() {
    var child = spawn('ls', ['/tmp']);
    var pid = child.pid;

    var wrappedChildStdoutOn = Meteor.wrapAsync(child.stdout.on, child.stdout);
    var wrappedChildStderrOn = Meteor.wrapAsync(child.stderr.on, child.stderr);
    var wrappedChildOn = Meteor.wrapAsync(child.on, child);

    // this insert() breaks upcoming insert() calls!
    Stuff.insert({pid: pid, date: new Date(), type: 'dummy', data: 'dummy'});

    wrappedChildStdoutOn('data',  function (data) {
      Stuff.insert({pid: pid, date: new Date(), type: 'stdout', data: data.toString()});
    });

    wrappedChildStderrOn('data', function (data) {
      Stuff.insert({pid: pid, date: new Date(), type: 'stderr', data: data.toString()});
    });

    wrappedChildOn('exit', function (code) {
      Stuff.insert({pid: pid, date: new Date(), type: 'exit', code: code});
    });
  }
});
```

What's up with that first `insert()` call?

[Here's a Meteor app demonstrating the issue](https://gitlab.com/meonkeys/meteor-async-spawn-issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` takes a bit of time, so `ls` finishes its output before the `insert` completes. By the time you've put the event handler in place, it's too late.

You can fix the issue by moving the first `insert` to the end, moving the first `insert` before the `spawn` call, or adding a no-op `function () {}` callback to the `insert` so it's called asynchronously.

Comment: Ah, of course! Meteor makes sure the following lines don't execute until the `insert()` finishes. Thanks!